# document length in lucene 4.0

Tags: lucene

as I've read the documentation of the lucene 4.0, now this library stores some statistics as in order to compute different scoring models, one of them bm25. Is there a way, besides fetching a document, to fetch its length too?

Comment: What is the length of document? The number of bytes/codepoints/fields?

Comment: it is a number of terms, same length as used to compute BM25, I know this statistic exists in the Lucene 4, as otherwise bm25 computation wouldn't be possible, but I don't know how to fetch it?

Answer (score 2):

You can store whatever you want from FieldInvertState into the 'norm', and it doesn't have to be a 8 bit float either.

The default is a lossy storage of the length, if you want the actual exact length, maybe you choose to use a short (16bits) per document or something else instead.

See Similarity.computeNorm

Comment: can you give me an example on how to retrieve doc length? I don't quite understand your reply.. being a bit more specific would certainly be helpful for me.
"See Similarity.computeNorm", see where? I'm using Lucene version 4.0

Comment: should I compute this norm at index time and store it as a field in index, or I can retrieve the length without having to store anything?