# lucene 4.0 statistics

Tags: java, lucene

although this is a second time I'm posting the same question, [the first one is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636641/document-lenght-in-lucene-4-0), but no answer, or partial answer. I've been struggling with this issue, and lost in the lucene api...

What I'm interested is, to get the document length from the Lucene. When I use searcher.explain (using bm25), I see that this feature exists, but I only need to fetch it.

I would highly appreciate an example, as I'm new to Lucene, just a point to API won't help.

One naive way to do it is to store this length in a seperate field, by using `string.length()` from java, and on query time retrieve it, however, this fature already exists (otherwise bm25 won't work) hence I don't want to store something redundatly.

I would highly appreciate it if you'd give a more detailed explanation on how to achieve this with the lucene 4.0, and if you're not able to provide and answer, please do not reply just for sake of replying (as then others are not reading my post thinking that it is solved!!!!), nor don't send me pointer to api (e.g. See Similarity.computeNorm by Robert Muir) because this won't help me. I need more details, like how to use this FieldInvertState, or Similarity.computeNorm??? On query time or index time??? small fragment of code would be helpful, you have to consider that I'm not an expert here, otherwise I wouldn't be asking

thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions just because you don't like reading documentation. I pointed you at the relevant documentation for how to work with these statistics, so that you could then move forward with your application. Fact: lucene doesn't store the document length (or any other per-document statistic) unless you do so in your Similarity yourself. I know this because for Lucene 4.0 I wrote the API in question.

Comment: you haven't given details, now I know that I should do it at index time (init. I thought at query time), but in the API there is no example on how to do it, in index I can only store documents, not similarity object.. Can you post a piece of code how to insert this metric in the index?

Comment: I gave you a link to Similarity.computeNorm, and there are a host of scoring systems that use document length in Lucene (you can look at their code). Your question doesn't give enough information: what is document length (is it the # of original terms or the number of analyzed terms after things like synonyms are added)? what level of precision do you need; norms are fully loaded into memory, so how many bytes/document are you willing to spend in RAM for this statistic? do you need to also support index-time boosting? These are important decisions that affect performance and relevance.

Comment: document length in my case is simply a number of analyzed terms. The reason for this is that I want to dampen the effect of very large documents vs very short documents, therefore I want to find the length of a document in order to do so. So basically, when I print top-k documents, I want to be able to use this factor (doc length).

But, this similarity object is abstract and I have no idea how to utilize it. I thought of simply creating a new field per doc, and insert contents.toString().length, as I couldn't get it how this Similarity.ComputeNorm works.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the newer the Lucene version you look at, the more daunting its complexity. Sometimes it helps to read the docs on an earlier version to see the basic principles more clearly.

Now to your case... Similarity is a Strategy-kind of object that you assign to the whole indexing process (IndexWriterConfig.setSimilarity). Its methods will be called to compute various pieces of information about each Document, and each of its Fields, being added to the index. So what Robert is suggesting here is to make your Similarity subclass (take the docs' advice and don't subclass Similarity directly, but rather one of the existing implementations, like DefaultSimilarity). Override the computeNorm method to produce the number that you want for the passed-in field. By default Lucene already computes that norm so that it tones down long fields, so I guess you have something more specific than that on your mind.

I would warmly suggest getting a hold of Lucene In Action if you want to get serious about leveraging Lucene.